iOS Swift WKWebView not loading Stencil JS Web component
I am traying to create Web component using stencil JS . Stencil build folder which has index.html actually loads the my stencil component. This Web components works fine on Mac OS Safari browser and Android WebView however same build folder does not load on iOS WKWebView so I would like to ask the question to the stencil community does stencil web components are compatible with iOS WKWebView browser if yes then what would be probable root cause for not loading web component on iOS WKWebView. I have implemented WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate callbacks on the Swift ViewController which includes WKWebView instance. Normal HTML works fine however not showing content which embedded on the Stencil component. I have also checked all the required build files are available on the resource path. Below is the index.html code
<!doctype html><html dir ="ltr" lang="en" ><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0"><title>Stencil Component Starter</title><script type="module" src="/build/demo.esm.js" data-stencil></script><script nomodule="" src="/build/demo.js" data-stencil></script></head><body><my-component first="param1" middle="param2" last="param3"></my-component></body></html>

